# How to number each consecutive night in a pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

In Python 3x I have some filled lists and I have put these in a pandas dataframe with 'ID' and 'Time' as columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'UTCTime': UTCTime})
print(df)

ID              UTCTime
3    4  2021-04-03 21:56:53
4    5  2021-04-03 21:56:55
5    6  2021-04-03 21:56:57
6    7  2021-04-03 22:00:07
7    8  2021-04-03 22:00:09
8    9  2021-04-03 22:00:11
9   10  2021-04-03 22:05:08
10  11  2021-04-03 22:05:10
...
```

So this is what the data looks like, ongoing for several months. The interval between timestamps is not equal.

But now I want to add an extra column 'NightID' and identify each consecutive night and give it a unique number. So  select time between 18:00 and 06:00 call it '1' and on to the next night, call it '2' and so forth for the whole dataset.
So it will look like this:

```
ID  UTCTime  nightID
1   27/04/2021 18:00    1
2   27/04/2021 21:05    1
3   28/04/2021 01:50    1
4   28/04/2021 02:25    1
5   28/04/2021 02:30    1
6   28/04/2021 05:59    1
7   28/04/2021 15:00    0
8   28/04/2021 18:00    2
9   28/04/2021 19:40    2
10  28/04/2021 23:50    2
11  29/04/2021 00:05    2
12  29/04/2021 00:35    2
13  29/04/2021 01:55    2
14  29/04/2021 02:30    2
15  29/04/2021 05:59    2
16  29/04/2021 06:01    0
17  29/04/2021 18:01    3
18  29/04/2021 22:30    3
19  29/04/2021 22:35    3
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

All help is much appreciated!

Kind regards, Martijn

Comment: How should a time like 7:00 be considered? Is it part of the next night or should it be excluded and not numbered? Is if 5:59 is the current night, is 6:00 on the dot the next day or part of the current night?

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. Yes the day can be excluded. 05:59:59 is night and 06:00:00 is day. Same for 17:59:59 is day and 18:00:00 is night.

Comment: extra info: the day can be excluded or given a value of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```py
# Ensure UTCTime is DateTime
df['UTCTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTCTime'])

# Mask To get Times We're interested in
m = (18 <= df['UTCTime'].dt.hour) | (df['UTCTime'].dt.hour < 6)
# Shift Values Between Start and End Time so that they appear on the same date
# (Eg. 5 am becomes 11 pm the previous day)
df['OffsetTime'] = df['UTCTime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=6)
# Create Group For Each Day
df['NightId'] = np.where(
    m, df['OffsetTime'].dt.date.astype('category').cat.codes + 1, 0
)

print(df)
```

Source:

```
   ID            UTCTime
3   4   2021-04-03 18:00
4   5   2021-04-03 21:05
5   6   2021-04-04 05:59
6   7   2021-04-04 15:00
7   8   2021-04-04 18:00 
8   9   2021-04-04 19:40
```

Output:

```
   ID             UTCTime          OffsetTime  NightId
3   4 2021-04-03 18:00:00 2021-04-03 12:00:00        1
4   5 2021-04-03 21:05:00 2021-04-03 15:05:00        1
5   6 2021-04-04 05:59:00 2021-04-03 23:59:00        1
6   7 2021-04-04 15:00:00 2021-04-04 09:00:00        0
7   8 2021-04-04 18:00:00 2021-04-04 12:00:00        2
8   9 2021-04-04 19:40:00 2021-04-04 13:40:00        2
```

---

Together without the extra variables and columns

```py
df['NightId'] = np.where(
    (18 <= df['UTCTime'].dt.hour) | (df['UTCTime'].dt.hour < 6),
    (df['UTCTime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=6)).dt.date.astype('category').cat.codes + 1,
    0
)
```

```
   ID             UTCTime  NightId
3   4 2021-04-03 18:00:00        1
4   5 2021-04-03 21:05:00        1
5   6 2021-04-04 05:59:00        1
6   7 2021-04-04 15:00:00        0
7   8 2021-04-04 18:00:00        2
8   9 2021-04-04 19:40:00        2
```

Comment: @ Henry Ecke that is very useful and does the trick. I also appreciate the comments you added. When I imported the NumPy it worked just fine! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift` to find date change and use `cumsum` to create nightID.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': range(8), 'UTCTime': pd.to_datetime(['2021-04-03 14:56:53',
                                                              '2021-04-03 18:00:00',
                                                              '2021-04-03 18:56:53',
                                                              '2021-04-04 05:03:24',
                                                              '2021-04-04 06:00:00',
                                                              '2021-04-04 06:10:09',
                                                              '2021-04-04 17:10:34',
                                                              '2021-04-04 18:20:03'])})

time_shifted = df['UTCTime'] + datetime.timedelta(hours = 6)
is_night = (time_shifted.dt.hour < 12)
night_id = (time_shifted.dt.date != time_shifted.dt.date.shift(1)) & (time_shifted.dt.date.shift(1).notna())
night_id = night_id.cumsum()
df['nightID'] = 0
df.loc[is_night, 'nightID'] = night_id
```

```
    ID  UTCTime             nightID
0   0   2021-04-03 14:56:53 0
1   1   2021-04-03 18:00:00 1
2   2   2021-04-03 18:56:53 1
3   3   2021-04-04 05:03:24 1
4   4   2021-04-04 06:00:00 0
5   5   2021-04-04 06:10:09 0
6   6   2021-04-04 17:10:34 0
7   7   2021-04-04 18:20:03 2
```

Comment: Hi Z Li, thanks for taking the effort to answer my question. I tried your code. It works fine but now the night changes at a date increment.

Comment: I edited my initial question, hopefully to better explain the problem

Comment: @Z Li that is very useful and does the trick. Many thanks!